# R: Aggregating History By ID By Date

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate

I have a large data set that has unique IDs for individuals as well as dates, and each individual is capable of multiple encounters.

The below is code and an example of how this data might look:

```
strDates <- c("09/09/16", "6/7/16", "5/6/16", "2/3/16", "2/1/16", "11/8/16",      
"6/8/16", "5/8/16","2/3/16","1/1/16")
Date<-as.Date(strDates, "%m/%d/%y")
ID <- c("A", "A", "A", "A","A","B","B","B","B","B")
Event <- c(1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0)
sample_df <- data.frame(Date,ID,Event)

sample_df

         Date ID Event
1  2016-09-09  A     1
2  2016-06-07  A     0
3  2016-05-06  A     1
4  2016-02-03  A     0
5  2016-02-01  A     1
6  2016-11-08  B     0
7  2016-06-08  B     1
8  2016-05-08  B     1
9  2016-02-03  B     1
10 2016-01-01  B     0
```

I want to keep all attached information per encounter, but then aggregate the following historical information by id

1. Number of Previous Encounters
2. Number of Previous Events

As an example, let's look at Row 2.

Row 2 is ID A, so I would reference Rows 3-5 (which occurred prior to Row 2 Encounter). Within this group of rows, we see that Row 3 & 5 both had events.

Number of Previous Encounters for Row 2  = 3

Number of Previous Events for Row 2 = 2

Ideally, I would get the following output:

```
         Date ID Event PrevEnc PrevEvent
1  2016-09-09  A     1       4         2
2  2016-06-07  A     0       3         2
3  2016-05-06  A     1       2         1
4  2016-02-03  A     0       1         1
5  2016-02-01  A     1       0         0
6  2016-11-08  B     0       4         3
7  2016-06-08  B     1       3         2
8  2016-05-08  B     1       2         1
9  2016-02-03  B     1       1         0
10 2016-01-01  B     0       0         0
```

So far, I have tried working this problem in dplyr with mutate as well as summarise, both of which have not let me successfully restrict my aggregation to events that occurred previously for a specific ID. I have tried some messy For-loops with If-then statements, but really just wondering if a package or technique exists to simplify this process.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest impediment is the current sort order. Here, I stored an original index point, which I later used to re-sort the data (then removed it). Other than that, the basic idea is to count up from 0 for the encounters, and to use `cumsum` to count the events as they happen. To that end, `lag` is used to avoid counting the current event.

```
sample_df %>%
  mutate(origIndex = 1:n()) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  arrange(ID, Date) %>%
  mutate(PrevEncounters = 0:(n() -1)
         , PrevEvents = cumsum(lag(Event, default = 0))) %>%
  arrange(origIndex) %>%
  select(-origIndex)
```

Gives

```
         Date     ID Event PrevEncounters PrevEvents
       <date> <fctr> <dbl>          <int>      <dbl>
1  2016-09-09      A     1              4          2
2  2016-06-07      A     0              3          2
3  2016-05-06      A     1              2          1
4  2016-02-03      A     0              1          1
5  2016-02-01      A     1              0          0
6  2016-11-08      B     0              4          3
7  2016-06-08      B     1              3          2
8  2016-05-08      B     1              2          1
9  2016-02-03      B     1              1          0
10 2016-01-01      B     0              0          0
```

Comment: `0:(n() -1)` is `row_number() - 1L`? Also, I guess the orig index can be `row_number()`.

Comment: Yep, @Frank -- those should be equivalent. I am not sure why I haven't started using `row_number()` more often. Likely a lazy holdover from pre-tidyverse approaches.

Comment: Thank you very helpful way to view this! Lag is def. something I did not know about and happy to have it now!

Comment: I actually wanted to add on one more chunk to this question. Would I be able to add below or should I start a new question?

Comment: @EntryLevelR -- generally best to start a new question. I'd be ok with you dropping a comment linking to the updated version though.

Answer (score 2):

Or, if you want to try with `data.table`, you can use this:

```
library(data.table)

# Convert to data.table and sort
sample_dt <- as.data.table(sample_df)
sample_dt <- sample_dt[order(Date)]

# Count only the previous Events with 1
sample_dt[, prevEvent := ifelse(Event == 1, cumsum(Event) - 1, cumsum(Event)), by = "ID"]

# .I gives the row number, and .SD contains the Subset of the Data for each group
sample_dt[, prevEnc := .SD[,.I - 1], by = "ID"]

print(sample_dt)
          Date ID Event prevEvent prevEnc
 1: 2016-01-01  B     0         0       0
 2: 2016-02-01  A     1         0       0
 3: 2016-02-03  A     0         1       1
 4: 2016-02-03  B     1         0       1
 5: 2016-05-06  A     1         1       2
 6: 2016-05-08  B     1         1       2
 7: 2016-06-07  A     0         2       3
 8: 2016-06-08  B     1         2       3
 9: 2016-09-09  A     1         2       4
10: 2016-11-08  B     0         3       4
```

If you didn't know this [package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/data.table.pdf), there is an excellent [cheat sheet](https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/img/blog/data+table+cheat+sheet.pdf) for most of the operations.

Comment: Rather than caclulating `cumsum(Event)` twice, why not just `cumsum(Event) - (Event == 1)`

Answer (score 0):

As @Frank and @MarkPeterson point out, the biggest hurdle here is that the `Date` column is sorted in descending order. Another approach that does not require resorting the `Date` column:

```
library(dplyr)
res <- sample_df %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
                     mutate(PrevEnc=n()-row_number(),
                            PrevEvent=rev(cumsum(lag(rev(Event), default=0))))
```

Here, we use `row_number()` to determine the row index and `n()` to determine the number of rows (grouped by `ID`). Since the `Date` is sorted in descending order, the number of previous encounter is simply `n()-row_number()`. To compute the number of previous events, we again exploit the fact that the `Date` column is sorted in descending order and use `rev` to reverse the order of the `Event` column before `cumsum` the `lag` of this reversed column. We then use `rev` again to reverse the result back to the original order.

Using your data:

```
print(res)
##Source: local data frame [10 x 5]
##Groups: ID [2]
##
##         Date     ID Event PrevEnc PrevEvent
##       <date> <fctr> <dbl>   <int>     <dbl>
##1  2016-09-09      A     1       4         2
##2  2016-06-07      A     0       3         2
##3  2016-05-06      A     1       2         1
##4  2016-02-03      A     0       1         1
##5  2016-02-01      A     1       0         0
##6  2016-11-08      B     0       4         3
##7  2016-06-08      B     1       3         2
##8  2016-05-08      B     1       2         1
##9  2016-02-03      B     1       1         0
##10 2016-01-01      B     0       0         0
```