# R: Aggregating History by ID and By Specified Data

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

I asked a similar question before and got great help: [R: Aggregating History By ID By Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40551711/r-aggregating-history-by-id-by-date/40552233#40552233)

The difference was that for the former post I was interested in aggregating ALL historical information, but now I am hoping to specify only 90 days back.

Here is an example of how my data might look:

```
strDates <- c("09/09/16", "5/7/16", "5/6/16", "2/13/16", "2/11/16","1/7/16",
          "11/8/16","6/8/16", "5/8/16","2/13/16","1/3/16", "1/1/16")
Date<-as.Date(strDates, "%m/%d/%y")
ID <- c("A", "A", "A", "A","A", "A", "B","B","B","B","B", "B")
Event <- c(1,0,1,0,1,1, 0,1,1,1,0, 1)
sample_df <- data.frame(Date,ID,Event)
```

As well as the output:

[image]

**Background Information**

I want to keep all attached information per encounter, but then aggregate the following historical information by id back to 90 days.

1. Number of Previous Encounters in last 90 Days
2. Number of Previous Events in last 90 Days

**Example**

As an example, let's look at Row 2.

Row 2 is ID A, so I would reference Rows 3-6 (which occurred prior to Row 2 Encounter). Within this group of rows, we see that Rows 3,4,5 and all occurred within the last 90 days, with Row 6 happening outside of the time of interest.

Number of Previous Encounters in last 90 days from Row 2: 3 Encounters

Number of Previous Events in last 90 days from Row 2: 2 Events (5/6/16 and 2/11/16)

**Desired Output**

Ideally, I would get the following output:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's an alternative `data.table` solution that should be very efficient. This utilizes the new *non-equi* joins that were introduced in v 1.10.0 combined with `by = .EACHI` which allows you do calculations per join *while* joining

```
library(data.table) #v1.10.0
setDT(sample_df)[, Date2 := Date - 90] # Set range (Maybe in future this could be avoided)
sample_df[sample_df, # Binary join with itself
          .(Enc90D = .N, Ev90D = sum(Event, na.rm = TRUE)), # Make calculations
          on = .(ID = ID, Date < Date, Date > Date2), # Join by
          by = .EACHI] # Do calculations per each match
#     ID       Date       Date Enc90D Ev90D
#  1:  A 2016-09-09 2016-06-11      0     0
#  2:  A 2016-05-07 2016-02-07      3     2
#  3:  A 2016-05-06 2016-02-06      2     1
#  4:  A 2016-02-13 2015-11-15      2     2
#  5:  A 2016-02-11 2015-11-13      1     1
#  6:  A 2016-01-07 2015-10-09      0     0
#  7:  B 2016-11-08 2016-08-10      0     0
#  8:  B 2016-06-08 2016-03-10      1     1
#  9:  B 2016-05-08 2016-02-08      1     1
# 10:  B 2016-02-13 2015-11-15      2     1
# 11:  B 2016-01-03 2015-10-05      1     1
# 12:  B 2016-01-01 2015-10-03      0     0
```

Answer (score 2):

A partially vectorized `dplyr` solution, where you can combine `do` (to loop through groups) and `rowwise` operation (so that you can refer Date as the Date at each row, and `.$Date` as the whole `Date` column within each group):

```
sample_df %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    do(rowwise(.) %>% 
        mutate(PrevEnc90D = sum(Date - .$Date < 90 & Date - .$Date > 0), 
               PrevEvent90D = sum(.$Event[Date - .$Date < 90 & Date - .$Date > 0])))

#Source: local data frame [12 x 5]
#Groups: ID [2]

#         Date     ID Event PrevEnc90D PrevEvent90D
#       <date> <fctr> <dbl>      <int>        <dbl>
#1  2016-09-09      A     1          0            0
#2  2016-05-07      A     0          3            2
#3  2016-05-06      A     1          2            1
#4  2016-02-13      A     0          2            2
#5  2016-02-11      A     1          1            1
#6  2016-01-07      A     1          0            0
#7  2016-11-08      B     0          0            0
#8  2016-06-08      B     1          1            1
#9  2016-05-08      B     1          1            1
#10 2016-02-13      B     1          2            1
#11 2016-01-03      B     0          1            1
#12 2016-01-01      B     1          0            0
```

Comment: I appreciate the solution and will try it out shortly! I should have added that I do have a very small data set (<2K rows) so time/memory should not be a huge issue.

Answer (score 2):

A rather lengthy dplyr solution that uses more rows than are really required. The idea is to create a fully joined table for every date, then use window functions. This may be useful if different window calculations are needed.

```
library(dplyr)

dates <- data.frame(Date = seq(from = -90 + min(sample_df$Date), to = max(sample_df$Date), by=1)) 
extended_df <- data.frame(ID = unique(sample_df$ID)) %>%
  merge(dates) %>% 
  left_join(sample_df, by=(c("ID", "Date"))) %>% 
  arrange(ID, desc(Date)) %>%
  mutate(Encounter = as.integer(!is.na(Event)),
         Event = ifelse(is.na(Event), 0, Event)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(PrevEnc90D   = rollsum(lead(Encounter), k=90, fill=0, align="left"),
        PrevEvent90D  = rollsum(lead(Event),     k=90, fill=0, align="left")) %>%
  inner_join(sample_df[,c("ID", "Date")]) %>%
  arrange(ID, desc(Date))

extended_df
```

Source: local data frame [12 x 6]
Groups: ID [2]

```
       ID       Date Event Encounter PrevEnc90D PrevEvent90D
   <fctr>     <date> <dbl>     <int>      <dbl>        <dbl>
1       A 2016-09-09     1         1          0            0
2       A 2016-05-07     0         1          3            2
3       A 2016-05-06     1         1          2            1
4       A 2016-02-13     0         1          2            2
5       A 2016-02-11     1         1          1            1
6       A 2016-01-07     1         1          0            0
7       B 2016-11-08     0         1          0            0
8       B 2016-06-08     1         1          1            1
9       B 2016-05-08     1         1          1            1
10      B 2016-02-13     1         1          2            1
11      B 2016-01-03     0         1          1            1
12      B 2016-01-01     1         1          0            0
```

Answer (score 1):

And another idea that tries to avoid repetitive summations and relational operations when possible:

```
do.call(rbind, 
        lapply(split(sample_df, sample_df$ID), 
               function(x) {
                   i = nrow(x) - findInterval(x$Date - 90, rev(x$Date))
                   cs = cumsum(x$Event)
                   cbind(x, PrevEnc90D = i - (1:nrow(x)), PrevEvent90D = cs[i] - cs)
               }))
#           Date ID Event PrevEnc90D PrevEvent90D
#A.1  2016-09-09  A     1          0            0
#A.2  2016-05-07  A     0          3            2
#A.3  2016-05-06  A     1          2            1
#A.4  2016-02-13  A     0          2            2
#A.5  2016-02-11  A     1          1            1
#A.6  2016-01-07  A     1          0            0
#B.7  2016-11-08  B     0          0            0
#B.8  2016-06-08  B     1          1            1
#B.9  2016-05-08  B     1          1            1
#B.10 2016-02-13  B     1          2            1
#B.11 2016-01-03  B     0          1            1
#B.12 2016-01-01  B     1          0            0
```

The above assumes that "Date" is ordered decreasingly within each "ID" (which is pretty straightforward to be done if not the case). The main idea, here, is to (i) locate the previous 90th day for each date, (ii) calculate a cumulative sum once and upfront and, (iii) subtract the respective indices/`cumsum`s to obtain the output. I used the `split`/`lapply` route, here, to group by "ID", but I guess, it's easily transferable to any tool preferable.